# Chrome extension popup, pictures and links are not working

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm writing a chrome extension that creates a popup when the button is pressed. The popup is a simple HTML file that includes links and images. When I press the links on the popup nothing happens, and the pictures show up as empty white boxes.  Does anyone know how I could fix this? The picture files are saved in the extension folder if that makes a difference.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Not enough information. However, off the cuff, try using getURL for the [asset URLs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/extension.html#method-getURL).

Comment: My code for the pictures is <p><img src="directory file.png" width="609" height="495" /></p>.  the pictures are the biggest issue, the links i can live without.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're dealing with two different issues.
Regarding the non working links, the simplest way to deal with it is to add  to the HEAD section of your popup or a specific target to each link.

Other approach, for instance, involves associating onclick javascript events to open new browser tabs with the associated url.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check out the Getting Started Tutorial about how to write extensions at http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html?

It's got everything you need to walk through the basics of writing an extension that does almost exactly that.  There's also a link to debugging extensions, which will hopefully help you to figure out if it's something else that's going on.

Thanks!
PEte